# Counter Issue in Java Dice Game

Tags: java

Assignment Instructions:

-Prompt the user in main() if he she want to play the game or not. Display a brief description of how the game should be played first.
-Code a method that allows the user to play
-Code a method for the computer throwing two dices.
-Code a method that displays the outcome by showing what the user entered, the user to play as many times as he.she wish...**and each time, you must keep track of the number of wins and losses by the player.**
-Code a method that display the statistics for all games played **and as soon as the player chooses to abort the game. You must display the number of games played, how may were won, how many were lost, and the percentile for each**

---

My problem is keeping track of the number of wins and losses by the player and displaying the correct amount of games that was played, won and loss after multiple turns at the game. (Specifically in the stats() method) I tried to add to the userwins and userloss with "++" but it doesn't remember the amount of games played when the user plays 1 to play another game. If the ++ doesn't work, I believe I should do a counter for it. However, I don't know if this counter should go in main or within the Stats() method.

---

```
public class DiceGame_
{
    //declarations:
    static int answer = 1;//1 to continue or 0 to quit
    static Scanner get = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int guess = 0;
    static int dice1 = 0;
    static int dice2 = 0;
    static int dicesum = 0;
    static int games = 0;
    static int userWins = 0;
    static int userLoss = 0;
    static double percentW = 0;
    static double percentL = 0;
    static Random random = new Random();

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    //Display the game's description and Prompt the user if they would like to play
    System.out.println("In this game, you are playing against the computer. The computer will throw 2 dices"
            + " to randomly select 2 numbers between 1 and 6.\nYou will then guess a number between 2 and 12, if the number"
            + " you guess matches the sum of the two dices the computer throws,\nthen you win! Otherwise, the computer wins.");
    
    //input:
    while (answer != 0) //while will allow the user to play again
    {
        GuessNum(); //call GuessNum method
        DiceThrow();//call DiceThrow method     
                
        //Output:
        DispOutcome();//Display outcome method
        
        //ask user if they would like to continue
        System.out.println("Would you like to play again? Press 1 for yes or 0 for no: ");
        answer = get.nextInt();
                
    }//end while
    Stats();//Stats Method (Display # of games played, won and loss, and percentiles of wins/losses)

}//end main

//==========================================================
public static void GuessNum() //The user guesses a number Method
{
    System.out.println("Please enter a number between 2-12 for your guess.");
    guess = get.nextInt();
    while(guess < 2 || guess > 12) //will make sure the user is asked again if they enter a value greater than 12 or less than 2
    {
        System.out.println("You must select a number between 2 and 12! Please re-enter a guess: ");
        guess = get.nextInt();
    }//end while
}//end GuessNum method
//==========================================================
public static void DiceThrow() //The computer generates 2 numbers from dice rolls
{
    dice1 = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
    dice2 = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
    dicesum = dice1 + dice2;
}//end DiceThrow method
//==========================================================
public static void DispOutcome() //Displays the outcome of what the user entered, the values of the 2 dice thrown and who won
{
    System.out.println("Computer: Dice 1 = " + dice1 + " and Dice 2 = " + dice2);
    System.out.println("Player: entered " + guess);
    System.out.println("You played " + guess + " and the compuer threw " + dice1 + " and " + dice2 + 
            " for a total of " + dicesum + "....");
        {
        if(guess == dicesum)
        System.out.println("You won!");
            else if(guess != dicesum)
                System.out.println("Sorry! You lost!");
        }//end if
        
}//end DispOutcome method
//==========================================================
public static void Stats() //Displays the stats of the game (wins, losses, percentile of each)
{
    
    {
    if(guess == dicesum)
        userWins ++; //adds 1 to the user's win count if the user wins a game
    else if (guess != dicesum)
        userLoss ++; //adds 1 to the user's loss count if the user losses the game
    }
    games = (userWins + userLoss); //total of games is the losses + wins
    System.out.println("You've played: " + games + " games");
    System.out.println("You've won: " + userWins + " games");
    System.out.println("You've loss: " + userLoss + " games");
    percentW = (userWins / games);
    percentL = (userLoss / games);
    System.out.println ( String.format("Your win percentage is %.2f", + (percentW * 100)) + "%");
    System.out.println ( String.format("Your loss percentage is %.2f", + (percentL * 100)) + "%");  
}//end Stats method
}//end class DiceGame_
```

Comment: What is the question you have? It is unclear. Please edit your question to make it clear what you are asking.

Comment: Can you put back the code and assignment?

Answer (score 0):

You are only calling the `Stats()` method once, when done, so the `userWins++` and `userLoss++` statements are only called once.  You should move those statements inside the `DispOutcome()` method so they get called for every game.  You already have a check for `(guess == dicesum)` there, which is where they go.

Comment: I have to include a Stats method so is there anyway I could I can keep the methods as is, but fix the counter problem in the Stats() method so its called repeatedly?

Comment: I think you assignment said to only call the `Stats()` method when the user is done so you don't have to call it repeatedly.  Just update your `DispOutcome()` method like this:    ``if (guess == dicesum) {
        System.out.println("You won!");  userWins++; }
    else if (guess != dicesum) {  
        System.out.println("Sorry! You lost!");  userLoss++; }`` (sorry about the bad formatting)

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 problems:

## Problem #1.

```
percentW = (userWins / games);
percentL = (userLoss / games);
```

The variables `userWins`, `games` and `userLoss` are all integers.  So the divisions are going to be treated as integer arithmetic.  That is going to cause `percentW` and `percentL` to be `0.0`.

Hint: to force the division to be done using floating point, convert either or both operands to be `double`.  Have you been taught how to convert from one primitive type to another?

## Problem #2.

The incrementing of the variables happens in the `Stats` method.  The Stats method is called only once.  Therefore the variables only get incremented once.

Hint: if the purpose of `Stats` is to print out the stats, then you are incrementing the score in the wrong method.

---

By the way, there are a few problems with style and other things:

- Method names should not start with an uppercase letter in Java.
- The indentation is inconsistent.  I suspect that you are using TAB characters in the source file.  This causes problems if you cut-and-paste code into Markdown ... and in other contexts.  For example Linux/Mac versus Windows!

  It is better to configure your IDE to use SP characters for indentation.
- There are issues with how you are using `{` ... `}`.  For example:

  ```
  {
      if (guess == dicesum)
          System.out.println("You won!");
      else if (guess != dicesum)
          System.out.println("Sorry! You lost!");
  }
  ```

  If you look at that, the braces serve no real purpose there.
- In a statement like this:

  ```
      GuessNum(); //call GuessNum method
  ```

  the comment is (IMO) harmful.  It says nothing that isn't totally obvious from the code.  In fact, all it really does is *distract* the reader.
- This code should be OO.  You are relying heavily on `static` methods and `static` variables.  (Maybe that is the next lesson ....)

Comment: I had the variables as double but it didn't do anything for my coding. One can't win half a game or play half a game etc..The division isn't the problem. The program runs fine when they user plays one game, it's when the user puts 1 to play again. After the play again, the program doesn't remember that the user has played previous games before hand.

Comment: Please read my answer again.  I am not talking about the type of the variable.  I am talking about the type of the variable.  I am talking about the type of the expression.

Comment: any indentation problems is due to me being new to stacoverflow's formatting. Also, I will fix the bracket issues but I can say that it's not causing the problem I'm referring to in my question. This is our second assignment and the professor asked for static variables and methods.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. My expressions match the variables. percentW and percentL aren't coming out to be 0.0, they give correct values

Comment: In that case, the code you have shown us is different to the code that you are running,  Sorry, but (for example) `3 / 5` in Java integer arithmetic is `0`, and the code you showed us is using integer arithmetic.

Comment: But anyway, I'm not going to argue with you.  Ultimately, it is your problem to find the bugs in your code .... however you choose to do it.

Comment: I changed the expressions and variables to double. Should I be moving the calculations within the Stats() method within the while loop to fix the counting issue?

Comment: See my last comment.